# Image and text alignment of mail template on different mail browsers and mail clients

Tags: html

I need help, actually I am working on an html email template.

My problem is the text and image alignment of mail template is not coming  properly in yahoo mail while opening in chrome browser(Working fine in IE).

So i tried to fix by assigning  width size along with style as follows:
`width="100%"  style="table-layout:fixed"` for table tag.

Now what is happening email template text and image alignment in  yahoo mail in chrome browser is working properly but not in IE.

Can please anyone tell the fix so that image and text alignment for all browser and mail clients should work properly.

Comment: Hello @Akanksha you look new there, you need to attach your code so we can help you :)

Comment: Hello Troyer..actually its normal html template that has image and text content.

Comment: edit the post and add the code, we need it to solve your problem :)

Comment: there is no easy fix to display emails in different browsers and different content providers. use tables and fixed pixel-dimensions/sizes as much as possible (opposite of normal web-development) and analyze which email-clients your newsletter will most likely be opened. we determined that we could neglect yahoo mail (but it may be different for you).